# Unity 5.2.2f and Facebook Unity SDK 7.2 AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_NewStringUTF()

Tags: java-native-interface, facebook-unity-sdk

I am having trouble when running Unity Facebook SDK in my app. The test app runs without problems, but in my app when I run `FB.Init(() => Debug.Log ("FB inited"));` I start getting these logs all the time. Even though it is inited I get weird crashes later and I don't get these logs in the test app. Can you please point me to what I am doing wrong.

```
I/Unity: Using Unity SDK v7.2.0
I/Unity: UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
I/Unity: UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity: Facebook.Unity.CustomLogger:Info(String) (at /Users/tarasleskiv/dev/repo/gs/MAIN-unity-sdk/unity-src/Assets/Facebook/Scripts/Utils/FacebookLogger.cs:105)
I/Unity: Facebook.Unity.FacebookLogger:Info(String) (at /Users/tarasleskiv/dev/repo/gs/MAIN-unity-sdk/unity-src/Assets/Facebook/Scripts/Utils/FacebookLogger.cs:49)
I/Unity: Facebook.Unity.FB:LogVersion() (at /Users/tarasleskiv/dev/repo/gs/MAIN-unity-sdk/unity-src/Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs:623)
I/Unity: Facebook.Unity.FB:Init(String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, String, HideUnityDelegate, InitDelegate) (at /Users/tarasleskiv/dev/repo/gs/MAIN-unity-sdk/unity-src/Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs:205)
I/Unity: Facebook.Unity.FB:Init(InitDelegate, HideUnityDelegate, String) (at /Users/tarasleskiv/dev/repo/gs/MAIN-unity-sdk/unity-src/Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs:147)
I/Unity: GetSocialDemoController:<DrawMainView>m__34() (at /Users/tarasleskiv/dev/repo/gs/MAIN-unity-sdk/unity-src/Asse
I/Facebook.Unity.FBDebug: Using Unity SDK v7.2.0
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_NewStringUTF()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_NewStringUTF()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_CallStaticObjectMethod(00100bde, 7412f318 
D/Unity: >          , 00100bd6
D/Unity: >          , 00200001
D/Unity: >          , 00200005
D/Unity: >          , 00000001
D/Unity: >          )
D/Unity: ? getMethodID("java.lang.Class", "forName", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;", static)
D/Unity: ! Class Class.forName(String);
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_FromReflectedMethod()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_NewStringUTF()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_CallStaticObjectMethod(00100bd6, 70046a88 
D/Unity: >          , 00000001
D/Unity: >          )
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_GetObjectClass()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_NewGlobalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_NewGlobalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_NewGlobalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteGlobalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteGlobalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_NewStringUTF()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_NewStringUTF()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_CallStaticObjectMethod(00100bde, 7412f318 
D/Unity: >          , 00100c5e
D/Unity: >          , 00100001
D/Unity: >          , 00100005
D/Unity: >          , 00000001
D/Unity: >          )
D/Unity: ? getMethodID("com.facebook.unity.FB", "GetSdkVersion", "()Ljava/lang/String;", static)
D/Unity: ! String FB.GetSdkVersion();
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_FromReflectedMethod()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_CallStaticStringMethod(00100c5e, 74199ad8)
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
I/Unity: Using Unity SDK v7.2.0 with FBAndroidSDK/4.7.0
I/Unity: UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
I/Unity: UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity: Facebook.Unity.CustomLogger:Info(String) (at /Users/tarasleskiv/dev/repo/gs/MAIN-unity-sdk/unity-src/Assets/Facebook/Scripts/Utils/FacebookLogger.cs:105)
I/Unity: Facebook.Unity.FacebookLogger:Info(String) (at /Users/tarasleskiv/dev/repo/gs/MAIN-unity-sdk/unity-src/Assets/Facebook/Scripts/Utils/FacebookLogger.cs:49)
I/Unity: Facebook.Unity.FB:LogVersion() (at /Users/tarasleskiv/dev/repo/gs/MAIN-unity-sdk/unity-src/Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs:616)
I/Unity: Facebook.Unity.FB:OnDllLoaded() (at /Users/tarasleskiv/dev/repo/gs/MAIN-unity-sdk/unity-src/Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs:597)
I/Unity: Facebook.Unity.CompiledFacebookLoader:Start() (at /Users/tarasleskiv/dev/repo/gs/MAIN-unity-sdk/unity-src/Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs:794)
I/Unity:  
I/Unity: (Filename: /Users/tarasleskiv/dev/repo/gs/MAIN-unity-sdk/unity-src/Assets/Facebook/Scripts/Utils/FacebookLogger.cs Line: 105)
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_NewStringUTF()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_NewStringUTF()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_CallStaticObjectMethod(00100bde, 7412f318 
D/Unity: >          , 00100bd6
D/Unity: >          , 00000001
D/Unity: >          , 00200005
D/Unity: >          , 00000001
D/Unity: >          )
D/Unity: ? getMethodID("java.lang.Class", "forName", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;", static)
D/Unity: ! Class Class.forName(String);
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_FromReflectedMethod()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_NewStringUTF()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_CallStaticObjectMethod(00100bd6, 70046a88 
D/Unity: >          , 00100001
D/Unity: >          )
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_GetObjectClass()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_NewGlobalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_NewGlobalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_NewGlobalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteGlobalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteGlobalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_NewStringUTF()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_NewStringUTF()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_CallStaticObjectMethod(00100bde, 7412f318 
D/Unity: >          , 00100c5a
D/Unity: >          , 00200001
D/Unity: >          , 00000005
D/Unity: >          , 00000001
D/Unity: >          )
D/Unity: ? getMethodID("android.util.Log", "i", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I", static)
D/Unity: ! int Log.i(String, String);
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_FromReflectedMethod()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_NewStringUTF()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_NewStringUTF()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_CallStaticIntMethod(00100c5a, 700fb208 
D/Unity: >          , 00000001
D/Unity: >          , 00100005
D/Unity: >          )
I/Facebook.Unity.FBDebug: Using Unity SDK v7.2.0 with FBAndroidSDK/4.7.0
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteGlobalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_NewStringUTF()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_NewStringUTF()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_CallStaticObjectMethod(00100bde, 7412f318 
D/Unity: >          , 00100c5e
D/Unity: >          , 00100001
D/Unity: >          , 00200005
D/Unity: >          , 00000001
D/Unity: >          )
D/Unity: ? getMethodID("com.facebook.unity.FB", "SetUserAgentSuffix", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", static)
D/Unity: ! void FB.SetUserAgentSuffix(String);
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_FromReflectedMethod()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_NewStringUTF()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_CallStaticVoidMethod(00100c5e, 74199d08 
D/Unity: >          , 00200001
D/Unity: >          )
V/com.facebook.unity.FB: SetUserAgentSuffix(Unity.Unity.7.2.0)
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_NewStringUTF()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_NewStringUTF()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_CallStaticObjectMethod(00100bde, 7412f318 
D/Unity: >          , 00100c5e
D/Unity: >          , 00000001
D/Unity: >          , 00100005
D/Unity: >          , 00000001
D/Unity: >          )
D/Unity: ? getMethodID("com.facebook.unity.FB", "Init", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", static)
D/Unity: ! void FB.Init(String);
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_FromReflectedMethod()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_NewStringUTF()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_CallStaticVoidMethod(00100c5e, 74199b10 
D/Unity: >          , 00100001
D/Unity: >          )
V/com.facebook.unity.FB: Init({"appId":"1470803889832802","cookie":true,"logging":true,"status":true,"xfbml":false,"channelUrl":"/channel.html","frictionlessRequests":true})
D/com.facebook.unity.FB: KeyHash: 8Sfsdh7a+RTmYuK684c4Xao7B9I=
V/com.facebook.unity.FB: sending to Unity OnLoginComplete({"permissions":"public_profile,user_friends,email","opened":true,"expiration_timestamp":"1451060655","access_token":"CAAU5sDdjQ2IBAJhv8vYryorhXtQqocZCknnlGnpTbWWRVFz0ZBEVQIisrIy5SRKsB3h1jPqBJon7GPnFMqZBNWXXZBpxUqstkOtpvtRbwZAHk31pUN6kHEuBCbDK8gJEnbN7omKZB2zTZBnGZBXrqZBlSDIHoZCtCdfPRYTUWJcpjav2aJxRguyyIlJyfZComD5j9dY7giiZAecCOLFZB9LrtrlXx0sFiitj7s0lgQRvg7Ye9JgZDZD","user_id":"129315734079840","declined_permissions":"","key_hash":"8Sfsdh7a+RTmYuK684c4Xao7B9I=\n"})
D/com.facebook.unity.FB: KeyHash: 8Sfsdh7a+RTmYuK684c4Xao7B9I=
V/com.facebook.unity.FB: sending to Unity OnInitComplete({"key_hash":"8Sfsdh7a+RTmYuK684c4Xao7B9I=\n"})
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_ExceptionOccurred()
D/Unity: > AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_DeleteLocalRef()
I/Unity: FB inited
I/Unity: UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
I/Unity: UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity: GetSocialDemoController:<DrawMainView>m__3C() (at /Users/tarasleskiv/dev/repo/gs/MAIN-unity-sdk/unity-src/Assets/GetSocialDemo/Scripts/GUI/GetSocialDemoController.cs:292)
I/Unity: Facebook.Unity.FacebookBase:OnInitComplete(String) (at /Users/tarasleskiv/dev/repo/gs/MAIN-unity-sdk/unity-src/Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FacebookBase.cs:208)
I/Unity: Facebook.Unity.FacebookGameObject:OnInitComplete(String) (at /Users/tarasleskiv/dev/repo/gs/MAIN-unity-sdk/unity-src/Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FacebookGameObject.cs:52)
I/Unity:  
I/Unity: (Filename: /Users/tarasleskiv/dev/repo/gs/MAIN-unity-sdk/unity-src/Assets/GetSocialDemo/Scripts/GUI/GetSocialDemoController.cs Line: 292)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution, the thing is that Facebook Unity SDK is now setting `AndroidJNIHelper.debug = true` and I had crashes because I am calling some JNI methods each frame. Changed to `false` and optimized methods calls and everything is working fine now.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm not calling any JNI methods. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by calling them each frame. Do you mean you're manually accessing java code (via reflection or w/e) and calling it perframe? Why would you do that?